How many roots are there of $(x^2-3)(x^3-3)$ in $K$, where $K$ is the splitting field of $x^3-1$ over $\mathbb F_{11}$?
Problem: How many roots are there of $(x^2-3)(x^3-3)$ in $K$, where $K$ is the splitting field of $x^3-1$ over $\mathbb F_{11}$?
I checked that only $\bar 1 \in \mathbb F_{11}$ is root of $x^3-1 \implies$ $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ which $(x^2+x+1)$ doesn't have root in $\mathbb F_{11}$.
I played such things over $\mathbb Q$ not over a finite field. I know that $(x^2+x+1)$  has roots $\frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{\sqrt3i}{2}$ so the splitting field will be $\mathbb{Q} \left(\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}, \frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)=\mathbb Q(w,w^2)=\mathbb Q(w)$ over $\mathbb Q$. Is it directly $\mathbb F_{11} (w)$ where $w$ is the root of $(x^2+x+1)$?
I don't know the procedure for finite fields. What should I need to do? On the other hand, if I determine the splitting field then I can manage the main problem.

The splitting field is (with some abuse of notation) $\Bbb{F}{11}(\omega,\sqrt3,\root3\of3)$. You already observed that $x^2+x+1$ has no roots in $\Bbb{F}{11}$, so adjoining $\omega$ gives a quadratic extension. What about the polynomials $x^2-3$ and $x^3-3$? How do they factor over $\Bbb{F}{11}$? Hint: because there are ten elements in the multiplicative group of this prime field, and $\gcd(3,10)=1$ cubing is a bijection from $\Bbb{F}{11}$ to itself.

Hints:

$x^n-1$ has $n$ distinct solutions in a field $\mathbf F$ iff the group of units $\mathbf F^*$ has a cyclic subgroup of order $n$.
Let $\mathbf F$ be a splitting field of $p(x)=x^n-k$ then $k$ is a perfect $n$-th root in $\mathbf F$ and roots of $p(x)$ are of the form $\lambda\sqrt[n]k$ where $\lambda\in\mathbf F$ is a root of $x^n-1$.
Group of units of a finite field is cyclic so converse of Lagrange's theorem holds here.


$\mathbb F_{11}^*$ is a cyclic group of order $10$ so all elements in here are perfect cubes. Check that the kernel of the homomorphism $x\mapsto x^3$ on $\mathbb F_{11}^*$ is trivial.
Exactly half the elements of $\mathbb F_{11}^*$ are perfect squares (fortunately, $3$ is among them). We have $(\pm 5)^2\equiv 3\pmod{11}$.
Now back to our polynomial,
$$p(x)=(x^2-3)(x^3-3)=(x-5)(x+5)(x^3-3)$$
We do have $\sqrt[3]{3}\in \mathbb F_{11}^*$ but there's no element of order $3$ here because $3\nmid \lvert \mathbb F_{11}^*\rvert$.
Consider an extension to $\mathbb F_{11^2}$. Here, $\lvert \mathbb F_{11^2}^*\rvert=120$ and $3\mid 120$ so, there is a unique cyclic subgroup $\{1,t,t^2\}$ of order $3$ in $\mathbb F_{11^2}^*$. Okay, this is the splitting field of $p(x)$.
$$p(x)=(x-5)(x+5)(x-\sqrt[3]{3})(x-t\sqrt[3]{3})(x-t^2\sqrt[3]{3})$$
That makes $5$ distinct roots because $t\neq t^2$ and $\sqrt[3]{3}\neq 5$.
